# How to disable error recover in antlr3

Tags: antlr3

If we don't want parser to 'recover' from errors, how to disable recovery and 
just let exception slip out in antlr3 ?

I get a solution on http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2006-September/017536.html
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted link is pretty much spot on.

You override the error recovery methods, mismatch is only one of them, There are a few, depending on the error.

I don't have the code in front of me right now, but look at all the mismatch methods in the parser file.